# Advanced Custom Fields plugin : displaying a field while omitting the p tags

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

In Advanced Custom Fields plugin, is it possible to display a WYSIWYG editor field in which `p` tags are omitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip_tags()` is not bad, but there may be a lot of tags you'll have to allow. So maybe you can use `str_replace()` to only get rid of the `<p>`-tag:

```
<?php 
  $field = get_field('wysiwyg'); // your wysiwyg field data
  $strip = array('<p>','</p>'); // search for <p>
  echo str_replace($strip,'',$field);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Natively, I don't believe there is a way to do that. Are you looking to remove just P tags, or all html tags? In your template, you could use:

```
    strip_tags($text,'<a><img><strong><b><em><i>')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php